# Using MATLAB to compute all the integers the satisfy a condition

Tags: matlab

I want to compute using MATLAB all the integers `x` such that `x^2-2x<2000`, but I am having problems in the displaying part because when I run my code MATLAB seems not to finish. My code is as follows:

```
x=100;
    while x^2+2x-2000>=10^-6
        x=x-20;
    if x^2+2x-2000<10^-6
            disp(x)
        end

    end
```

I think the wrong part is when I type `disp(x)` in the `while` loop, but I don't know how to fix it.

NOTE: I am using the `10^-6` to avoid rounding errors

Can someone help me to fix this code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computationally, finding all integers that satisfy this condition will need some help from a quick insight into this problem. Otherwise, you'll have to test all the integers, which is impossible since there is infinite number of integers. Analytically, finding all the integers that satisfy the condition `x^2-2x < 2000` means finding the integers that lies within the intersection of the curve `x^2 - 2x` and `y = 2000`.

Let's first take a look at the problem by plotting it:

```
x = -500:.1:500;
y = x.^2 - 2*x;
plot(x, y, 'color', 'g')
hold on
line([-200 200], [2000 2000], 'color', 'r')
```

[image]

You can easily see that you can limit your search to at least between -100 and 100. You can store the value in an array

```
results = []    % Declare empty array first and append value later. 
for x = -100:100
    if x^2 - 2*x < 2000
        disp(x)
        results = [results,x];  % Using a bracket to append value to the array.
    end
end
```

And a faster way to get results using [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/).

```
x = -100:100
results = x(x.^2 - 2*x<2000)
```

In the above code, x.^2 - 2*x < 2000 generates a logical array that has the same size as x. Each element stores the logical value that comes from the evaluating each element in x with the expression. You then use this as a mask to pick out only elements in x that satisfy this condition.

Answer (score 1):

If you add in some parentheses and use the correct syntax for `2*x`, it works.

```
x=100;
while (x^2+2*x-2000)>= (10^-6)
    x=(x-20);
if (x^2+2*x-2000) <10^-6
        disp(x)
    end

end
```

Comment: I've try it but it gives me 40, and want in fact a list of integers, what can I do in that case?

Comment: declare an array outside the while loop, and and append elements to it whenever the condition is met.

Comment: I am sorry for this but I don't remeber the comand to append and declare the array :) thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Building upon @User3667217's solution, you can also vectorise this:

```
x = -100:100;
y = x.^2-2*x;
tmp = y<2000;
results = y(tmp);
```

this will give you a speed up over the `for`-loop solution.